Why is the loss value of my model going up?
So I am experimenting with ML5JS and Mediapipe to train a model on sign language (specifically moving signs). My code makes mediapipe collect 3780 frames, process these and save them in a variable that looks like this:
    {
      "label": "wave",
      "vector": [        
        0.7023592591285706,
        0.9515798091888428,
        (etc. (3790 in total)
      ]
    }, (34 more examples)

I have 3 poses with about 35 examples in total. When I make ML5 train (with a neural network) my loss value appears to be going up.

I have the following parameters to my model: Learning rate: 0.15 epochs: 30 hidden units: 20. I have tried adjusting the number of hidden units to 2 and adjusting the learning rate to 0.0015 in case the issue was overfitting, this does not matter for the results
What is causing my learning rate to go up? Could this be the result of a small batch size?

I found out that the way I structured my data was too big for ml5js to handle, so I changed the way it is formatted.
Old situation:

{
  "label": "wave",
  "vector": [        
    0.7023592591285706,
    0.9515798091888428,
    (etc. (3790 in total)
  ]
}, (34 more examples)


New situation:

{
  "label": "wave",
  "vector": ([42 numbers (X & Y coords from mediapipe)],
            [(42 numbers (X & Y coords from mediapipe)],
            (up to 89 indexes for 90 frames)
}, (34 more examples)


You can use the normal learn function form ML5 to train your model. Changing my data structure improved my loss rate significantly.
Here is what the loss looks like right now:

